# Stop spring batch in failure

Tags: spring, spring-batch, exit

Bonjour,

I need to stop a running spring batch with Failure status if, in my reader, a test return true. How can I do this ? 
I actually use System.exit(-1), but I think that spring batch has his own way to stop running batch with different status.

here is the function in my reader from which I want to stop the batch:

```
private List<Test> getListTest() throws Exception {
    ...
            if (stop) {
            logger.error("Stop running batch");
            System.exit(-1);
            return null;
            }
    ...
}
```

Merci et bonne journée

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two ways to fail a spring batch job.

1. Simply throw an exception inside reader and spring batch will automatically stop the job with failed status .
2. You can use joboperator.stop() method to stop any running job . This method will send a signal to stop Job ,but job will be stopped only after the transaction gets completed .

Comment: Bonjour DevG,
the JobOperator interface seems to do what I want. thank you